# Одинаковый sku у товара и его вариаций в WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как можно в WooCommerce при создании или импорте товара присвоить sku товара его вариациям, чтобы он был одинаковый и у товара и у вариаций?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании товара надо сначала создать все вариации, а потом присвоить товару sku. Тогда все вариации получат sku основного товара.

Такой код обходит все товары, и перезаписывает sku. При этом вариации автоматически получают тот же sku, что и основной товар.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            $sku = $product->get_sku();
            if ( $sku ) {
                try {
                    $product->set_sku( $sku );
                    $product->save();
                } catch ( Exception $e ) {} // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine.
            }
        }
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Можно ли такое провернуть через функцию? Я знаю есть несколько генераторов sku, но они делают различные sku на основе названия или родительского sku.
Сейчас при импорте через WP All Import, создается товарная позиция, у которой указан артикул, вариации создаются автоматически на основе указанных атрибутов и у этих вариаций нет персонального артикула.
Поэтому стоит вопрос, как автоматически присвоить этим вариациям родительский sku.

Comment: Кодом можно сделать все, вопрос где. У товаров. созданных при импорте - есть sku?

Comment: Да, sku задается во время импорта.